# Overwrite styles of jQuery CSS framework

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an app that uses jQuery for certain parts such as the Autocomplete and Calendar Date Picker. I'm introducing a new style called .more-compact that will implement a smaller version of the app. This class is currently sitting in the div encompassing the entire app. This class works in reducing the heights, widths, and font sizes of almost everything. But when I try to do it for any jQuery elements, it won't work. This is how a typical style on the CSS doc looks:

```
.more-compact ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

But for the jQuery autocomplete element, it will only work if I remove the ".more-complete" part. I don't want this though because this is part of a single stylesheet, and I only want the font to be that size when the .more-compact version is being used.

Any ideas what is causing this nesting not to work? Is the jQuery stylesheet overwriting my own? The `<link>` for this stylesheet is the lowest on the doc, so it should take priority.

Comment: This question needs an [mcve] to be answerable. The solution below is a bad hack that lacks context and isn't guaranteed to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `!important`

```
.more-compact ul li {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

But try using more specific rules. By indicating one or more elements before the element you're selecting, the rule becomes more specific and gets higher priority

HTML

```
<div id="test">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#test span { color: green; }
div span { color: blue; }
span { color: red; }
```

Comment: I did try !important but for some reason it doesn't make a difference. Same with adding specific nested rules. I even simplified the code down so I'd only need 3 nested tags, but it still didn't work. The .more-compact styles work for everything but the jQuery and other added plugins. I'm thinking there's something over righting somewhere in the code.

Comment: @tneilson08 If the answer above didn't work, then why did you mark it as the accepted answer?